# How to setup the developer account in Beanstream payment gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway, user-accounts, beanstream

How to setup the developer account in Beanstream payment gateway?

I tried their documentation and also the Google. I filled up a form to apply for a account in their site. But there is no reply from them. But I found out that having test account is possible in Beanstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too late to answer the question but someone might still need it. Below is the link to get test account in beanstream. Note that you follow all the validations. Since validations are not applied well, you won't get what is the error while creating the account. To avoid such error, use company name which is unique.

http://developer.beanstream.com/quick-start/

Comment: Looks like this is their recent development. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted them again and got it.

- We cannot setup a test account by ourselves in Beanstream.
- We have to contact them through their form (https://www.beanstream.com/public/apply.asp) [They are likely to respond within 24 hours]
- IF for 6 months, the test account is inactive, it would get disabled.